# Working Form Validation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have been trying to roll my own form validation using a visual checkmark or X beside the form field on keyup. One problem I had was that on error or not it would spawn a new span after keyup was fired. So I tried to remove all of the elements after each key up so that I either got one span with a success or error message. This currently works, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this:

```
jQuery('input#firstname').keyup(function () {

    var text = jQuery(this).val();

    if (check_text(text) === false || text === '') {
        $(this).nextAll().remove();
        jQuery(this).after('<span class="form-error">Error</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll().remove();
        jQuery(this).after('<span class="form-success">Success</span>');
    }
});

/* Functions */

function check_text(text) {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/;
    return regex.test(text);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XBaKQ/1/

Comment: Looks good to me. Why do you think it needs improving?

Comment: Maybe better consolidation for speed, etc.

Comment: I don't think you'll really have a problem with speed because that's limited by how fast a person can type in this particular example.  The JS you have is plenty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add span next to each `input`

```
<input id="firstname" /><span class='msg'></span> <br>
<input id="lastname" /><span class='msg'></span>
```

and in your script set message like this :

```
      if (check_text(text) === false || text === '') {
        jQuery(this).next(".msg").html('<span class="form-error">Error</span>');
       } else {      
         jQuery(this).next(".msg").html('<span class="form-success">Success</span>');
      }
```

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/XBaKQ/4/)

Comment: This looks legit. I like the way it doesn't need the extra methods I used to remove the extra spans. Good stuff.

Comment: However, wouldn't empty <span> tags not be considered semantic HTML?

Comment: They are just placeholders for your error/success.. they are empty but you are going to use them with your script....so we can't really call them empty....

Comment: and i see a lot of validation plugin's using same kind of stuff